# Centos 7 systemd service start up not able to read file on network drive

Tags: linux-networking, centos7, systemd

I've read a bunch of systemd dependencies related on the web but still couldn't come up with one that works.  I'm not sure what the problem is.  The job is supposed to start on on reboot. It depends on network, autofs, rpc, and I've added a RequiresMountsFor, but still no luck. The unit still couldn't find a file on the network drive.  Any ideas appreciated.

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain hello.service
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

hello.service @11.520s
└─autofs.service @11.429s +88ms
  └─network.target @11.425s
    └─network.service @10.751s +674ms
      └─NetworkManager.service @1.326s +123ms
        └─basic.target @1.274s
          └─sockets.target @1.274s
            └─rpcbind.socket @1.274s
              └─sysinit.target @1.273s
                └─systemd-update-utmp.service @1.269s +2ms
                  └─auditd.service @1.204s +62ms
                    └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1.120s +82ms
                      └─rhel-import-state.service @1.111s +8ms
                        └─local-fs.target @1.109s
                          └─home.mount @734ms +261ms
                            └─dev-mapper-centos\x2dhome.device @734ms
```

This is the unit file:

```
$ cat hello.service
[Unit]
Description=Hello Tester
Requires=network-online.target autofs.service
After=network-online.target autofs.service
RequiresMountsFor=/path/to/file

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ls -l /path/to/file/on_nfs > /tmp/hello_tester.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here's the error.  I guess I can't specify that cmd line with multiple args like that.  But it is apparent that it can't see the file on the network when start up.

```
$ systemctl status hello.service
● hello.service - Hello Tester
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/hello.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-07-30 02:18:02 HKT; 2 days ago
  Process: 1760 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ls -l /path/to/file/on_nfs > /tmp/hello_tester.log (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 1760 (code=exited, status=2)

Jul 30 02:17:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Hello Tester.
Jul 30 02:17:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Hello Tester...
Jul 30 02:18:02 localhost.localdomain ls[1760]: /usr/bin/ls: cannot access /path/to/file/on_nfs: No such file or directory
Jul 30 02:18:02 localhost.localdomain ls[1760]: /usr/bin/ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory
Jul 30 02:18:02 localhost.localdomain ls[1760]: /usr/bin/ls: cannot access /tmp/hello_tester.log: No such file or directory
Jul 30 02:18:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: hello.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jul 30 02:18:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit hello.service entered failed state.
Jul 30 02:18:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: hello.service failed.
```

Comment: That clearly indicates that the file can not be accessed, so that is all you should focus on.  Does it work for you to run `ls -l /path/to/file/on_nfs` directly from the shell?

Comment: @Julie: yes, it does.  Only doesn't work when this unit runs after reboot.

Comment: Does that mount get loaded automatically when you boot the machine?

Comment: yes, that's why I added dependency on autofs and rpcbind.

Comment: and, the RequiresMountsFor

Comment: The `RequiresMountsFor` doesn't work when mount points are set to `noauto`, which is why I wanted to double-check.

Comment: Does autofs actually mount your remote mounts?

Comment: I didn't put the mount in /etc/fstab.  This is mounted by the auto fs, which is ondemand, not a static mount.  Would that be a problem?  I thought what auto fs does is when 'someone' request for it, it'll mount it on request.  In that case, it is the systemd unit job that asks for it.

Comment: @michael: yes, it does.  After I get on the machine some time after reboot, 'cd' into the /path/to/file/ directory always works.  It seems it's only after reboot, the job couldn't get into this dir.  I've looked at /var/log/messages and didn't see other notable errors.

Comment: Well that would explain everything.  `systemd` will not see your `autofs` mount and will simply ignore the requirement.  Since this job runs at boot, I really don't see any reason not to put it in your `/etc/fstab` which would solve your issue.

Comment: @JuliePelletier: really?  it doesn't work for autofs but only /etc/fstab?  I don't seem to be able to find any references to that.  Would you mind to point me?  thx

Comment: Haven't you tried it already?  No need for a reference when you can check it for yourself in 5 minutes.  Setting up dynamic auto mounts is made to allow them to be mounted on demand but you do not even have that need as you need it mounted during the boot-up process.  The `RequiresMountsFor` serves to ensure the system deals with that mount before loading your service.

Comment: @JuliePelletier: because my question was why my config didn't work?  I wasn't asking would changing the mount to static make it work.  Logically, if the dependency in systemd is set and start after autofs, shouldn't the command to 'ls' the dir 'request' nfs for the dir, just like I'd 'ls' interactively.   At that point, it should go and mount it.  I shouldn't even need the RequiresMountsFor.  That was more for to test it out why it didn't work...

Comment: also I believe having auto mount is better than static mount anyways.  Besides mount on demand (and unmount when no one needs it), one day if I remove this starter job, I no longer have dependency on the dir on boot up.  That makes start up dependency much easier to manage.  Isn't it?

Comment: Since you insist in being given a reference (that I found in 10 seconds), here you go: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html ...  search for noauto

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood what I mean, or I completed missed out something -- I want to find reference for systemd not working for auto.* files (e.g. auto.master, auto.direct map files for autofs).  I don't have an entry in /etc/fstab for the autofs to work.  It only need an entry in /etc/auto.master as a direct map. That's the one I'm not sure how it works with systemd.

Comment: to be clearer: auto.master includes a line '/- /etc/auto.direct', and /etc/auto.direct looks like '/path/to/file/on_nfs 192.168.1.1:/san_external/share/path'.  So, the machine runs nfs client, where the file path is mapped to a remote server's dir, using autofs.

Answer (score 0):

Just for paranoia, have you tried to access this file while logged in as user root? The root user doesn't have God rights when on an NFS partition unless the serving machine has granted them.

Comment: nope, I didn't login as 'root'.  Normally, root user can also see this NFS partition without problems.

Comment: So it was exported with no_root_squash by the server ?

Comment: yes, with that export

Comment: The "cannot access >" is, I am assuming because the ExecStart does not run the command through a shell, and so the file /tmp/hello_tester.log doesn't get created. However, the log entry "cannot access /path/to/file/on_nfs" needs to be got round first.

I wonder if this is a timing thing. It can take a little while to establish an automount. Maybe if you added the clauses to retry the service on failure, you'll catch it the second/third time round.